# WPF Datagrid grouping for variant depth of nesting

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have this class:

```
public class Milestone
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Milestone> children { get; set; }
}
```

and this list:

```
public ObservableCollection<Milestone> CurrentMilestones = new ObservableCollection<Milestone>();
```

Every CurrentMilestone can have or not have child milestones, that in turn can have or not have child milestones - thats variant level of nesting (can be up to 5 levels of nesting)

Is it possible to display such data `grouped` in `DataGrid`, with regard to the variant level of nesting?

Found this, but its for flattened data, doesn't work for me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/611674/nested-expander-control-in-datagrid

Comment: If you know the max depth, you can create nested lists inside list items. Visibility would be set accordingly.